# Copy to Output Option Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I don't know if I am just not looking in the right place or what but when I right-click a folder in the root of my .csproj I don't see an option anywhere to set it to copy to output (bin).

Comment: Only works on files, not folders.

Comment: ah thanks!  I guess something else is copying that folder but don't  see how that is.  I've looked in the solution dependencies, looked in various .csproj files including the one that contains that folder that is somehow magically being copied to the bin of the other project and still can't see how the heck that's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folders aren't copied to the bin directory.  Only files are.  If you click a file, you will see the Copy to Output Directory option.